# дожидаться выполнения Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый день. Есть функция которая загружает данные с помощью Аякс запрос к базе данные по Id пользователя

```
function getDialogToId(idVk){
    var pageRez='0'; 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://site.ru/ajax/ids.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'func=getDialogToId'  + '&idVk=' + idVk,                     
        dataType: 'json',                       
    }).done(function(rez) {                    
        pageRez =  rez.page;
    }).fail(function() {    
        alert('ОШИБКА, что-то не так');
    }); 

    return pageRez;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что как только я вызываю ее в цикле, переменные приходят undefined , подскажите в чем дело? почему функция не дожидается результата , который должен прийти в Аякс запросе, а сразу выдает не определенную переменную? и как это можно исправить? Спасибо.

вот код вызова:

```
getDialogToId('5093649');
```

Comment: Как в цикле вызываете, какая  переменная `undefined`? Добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: А вообще гляньте в сторону `promiseAll`

Answer (score -2):

Ajax выполняется асинхронно по умолчанию, т.е. ваш код продолжает выполняться, возвращает undefined и только много позже завершается выполнение ajax-запроса с присваиванием результата.

Самый простой (хоть и не самый лучший способ) - добавьте

```
async: false,
```

в ajax-запрос. Браузер выдаст предупреждение, но код будет работать так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: хоть и не самый лучший == за рекомендацию таких способов в приличном обществе бьют по шапке)

Comment: Спасибо, но соглашусь с прошлым комментатором, этот вариант совершенно не подходит.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму по шапке можно и в ответ получить. Приличным называется то общество, где не ехидничают, а дают лучшие ответы, разъясняя (не мне, я и без вас все знаю), почему предложенный ответ плох и какие у него подводные камни. Учитывая уровень подготовки пользователя  (по вопросу видно, что он вообще не догадывался ни о какой асинхронности) я предложил самое простое решение.

Comment: @Максим147 интересно было бы услышать, почему. Вот почему - совершенно )

Comment: @KAGGDesign, самое простое и в общем случае явно вредное решение.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму уровень дискуссии mail.ru

Comment: @KAGGDesign в смысле дискуссии? Вы предлагаете явно вредное решение не говоря чо том что оно вредное достаточно ясно. Я не хочу никому ничего доказывать, я хочу чтобы тот кто мимо проходил не использовал его а поискал еще.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму явно вредное оно только в вашей голове, более нигде. Было бы тотально вредным - не поддерживалось бы до сих пор.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, нет, не только. Это deprecated фича. Вы же понимаете почему deprecated фичи использовать плохо, да? (это уж не говоря о том что Вы толкаете автора вопроса с нормального пути на костыльно-хренаторский)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму я ждал этого ) вы фразу в мануале до конца прочитайте, переведите в ней слово with, а потом уж делайте заявления

Comment: @KAGGDesign, я то перевел и понял, а вот Вы кажется нет. Намекаю, задепрекейтить синхронный xhr придумали не в jQuery, источник другой) Загляните в него, там много интересного